# embedded system without login should have CSRF token?

Tags: csrf

As well known a lot embedded system is lake of memory.

Http server only can host 1-2 cookie/csrf token

1. Should I cache non-login csrf token?
2. how can I avoid CSRF without login?

Get more memory..

I only have 2k bytes memory for full system..